# Ordering Data In FireStore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have numeric data each in every document... I am getting the data using this code

```
 db.collection('Stations').orderBy("station","asc").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) =>{
  this.setState({
    stations:querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
      return {
        id: doc.id,
        station:doc.data().station
      }
    })
  })
});
```

And the data is not getting arranged properly as seen below:

[image: not getting arranged properly as seen below:-]

Answer (score 3):

You're ordering by string values, which use lexicographical ordering. And in lexicographical order `"100"` comes before `"2"`.

To fix your problem, have a field with only the numerical value, and order by that field. Alternatively pad the numbers so they all have the same length, because `"002"` comes before `"100`".

Also see:

- [How does Firestore query operation strings treat different data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504084/how-does-firestore-query-operation-strings-treat-different-data-types/49504203#49504203)
- [Firestore - Orderby Descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907271/firestore-orderby-descending/52912000#52912000)

Comment: How can I specify that the data is an integer in JS

Comment: You do that by writing a JavaScript number. This writes two fields, one as a number and one as a string. `doc.set({ number: 12, string: "12" })`