# Why `limit_to_last` not working in Firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

When running the code below I get the first item not the last. Why is that?

```py
async def example():
    db: google.cloud.firestore.AsyncClient = AsyncClient()
    await db.document("1/1").set({"a": "1"})
    await db.document("1/2").set({"a": "2"})
    last = (
        await (
            db.collection("1")
            .order_by("a")
            .limit_to_last(1) # <= not working - getting the first not last
            .get()
        )
    )[0].to_dict()
    first = (
        await (
            db.collection("1")
            .order_by("a")
            .limit(1)
            .get()
        )
    )[0].to_dict()
    print(first, last) # {'a': '1'} {'a': '1'}


asyncio.run(example())
```

The workaround is the use of descending ordering with `limit()`. But I don't understand - what is the purpose of the `limit_to_last()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your database schema looks like this:

```
db
|
--- 1 (collection)
    |
    --- 1 (document)
    |   |
    |   --- a: "1"
    |
    --- 2 (document)
        |
        --- a: "2"
```

Then the following query:

```
db.collection("1").order_by("a").limit_to_last(1)
```

Will indeed return:

```
{'a': '2'}
```

Because the last element in the results is the second document. I tested and it worked. However, when you want to store numbers, it's **not** recommended to store them as strings but as numbers. Why? Because when you order strings the order is [lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154176/how-to-order-data-from-firestore-in-flutter-orderby-not-ordering-correct/58154660#58154660).

Comment: Thanks. My scheme is exactly the same. I created database with `db.document("1/1").set({"a": "1"})`. If I change to `db.collection("1").document("1").set({"a": "1"})` - everything works as expected. Why is this?

Comment: I'm not sure why when you're using `.document("1/1")` doesn't work correctly, maybe perhaps of an escape character. However, it's best to differentiate from the beginning a collection from a document by calling `.collection("1").document("1")`.

Comment: I think your answer is helpful, thanks

Comment: You're very welcome, Andrey.