# Load firestore document data to LazyColumn Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to Android development, and I'm looking for guidance on how to load Firestore document data into a LazyColumn Jetpack Compose in ascending order.

***Here is my Document List In the Firebase Database***

[image: documents]

My document list in Firestore does not sort in ascending order. I tried to sort using query builder but the results were still the same. I was expecting the output to be Episode 1 until Episode 650.

***Here is my result***

[image: myresult]

Q: How to load Firestore data in ascending order in `LazyColumn`.

Update: I already insert index to my data so I can sort in ascending order.

[image: structure firebase]

Comment: On a different topic, it's best practice to avoid naming you collections the way you did here, because you can run into problems when there's a second game show with the same title or alike. It's better to use a unique identifier and then have a "name" field or "info" element in there (which could also contain translations, additional info etc). If you still choose to leave it human-readable, please avoid spaces and brackets as this can cause problems when migrating to a different provider in the future that doesn't support UNICODE names for collections.

Answer (score 0):

Simply generated code for your question.

> Your model class should look like below. Be careful with **url_1**. You should use the same for all documents in Firestore.

```
data class Content(
    val episode: String,
    val index: Int,
    val title: String,
    val url_1: String
)
```

> ViewModel

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    val itemList: MutableState<List<Content>> = mutableStateOf(emptyList())

    init {
        fetchItems()
    }

    private fun fetchItems() {
        firestore.collection("Running Man (Game-Show)")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                val items = mutableListOf<Content>()
                for (document in documents) {
                    val data = document.data
                    // Map Firestore document data to your custom Content class
                    val item = Item(
                        data["episode"] as String,
                        data["index"] as Int,
                        data["title"] as String,
                        data["url"] as String
                    )
                    items.add(item)
                }
                itemList.value = items
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.e("Firestore", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }
    }
}
```

And you can display it with this composable function.

```
@Composable
fun ItemList(itemList: List<Content>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(itemList) { item ->
            // Display each item in the LazyColumn
            Text(text = item.field1) // Replace with the actual field you want to display
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need help I receive error on Item [error] (https://prnt.sc/K0SX8YTEhABL)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for guidance on how to load Firestore document data into a LazyColumn Jetpack Compose in ascending order.

As far as I understand, it is not about the LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose but the order of the results the query returns. As I can see from your screenshot, the document IDs are set using this pattern "Episode 1", "Episode 2", ...

Please note that the document IDs in Firestore are always strings. This means that the default order in the Firebase Console or the default order of your documents that are returned by your query, is an order in which "Episode 109" is placed in the results before "Episode 9". This is happening because when your order stings, the [order is lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

To solve this, you might consider using the solution in the below answer:

- [How to order the nodes in firebase console based on key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647150/how-to-order-the-nodes-in-firebase-console-based-on-key)

By padding 0s as needed. Or you can create a query and [order the results by a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154176/how-to-order-data-from-firestore-in-flutter-orderby-not-ordering-correct/58154660#58154660) field. The above answer is for Realtime Database but the same rules apply in case of Firestore.

Comment: This could be done using ```Sort``` function in ```Kotlin```. So If you get unsorted data though you can do it in Kotlin.

Comment: @ChiragThummar That's not an option to get all the data an order the results on the client. You have to get the data already ordered from the server.

Comment: Hey SyahmiSam. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. Can I help you with other information?